# Why does Wolverine say these words when burying this person?

Tags: dialogue, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In Logan (2017), Wolverine say these words to himself when burying Professor X:

> It's got water, and... It's got water.

Why does he say that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logan's plan earlier in the movie was to buy a sailboat and sail to the ocean with the Professor, where they would spend their last days. Out on the sea, the Professor wouldn't pose a threat to other humans when he lost his control over his ability.

If I am not mistaken the Professor liked that idea - being out on the sea.

> When he died and Logan buried him, it was near a lake, so he was at least near water - Since Logan was emotional about the death of the Professor these were the only words he managed to say as a kind of eulogy.